# Error reading pdf using iText

Tags: java, itext, pdf-reader

I have written a simple program which reads from a pdf file, code is as shown below, I am uploading two pdf files which read the pdf and returns the data in string format, the problem is first pdf file is being read perfectly and when i try to read the same pdf again results in following error :

```
//Fetch media from media1
InputStream is;
is = media1.getStreamData();
PdfReaderUtility pru = new PdfReaderUtility();
String s1 = pru.readPdfFile(is);
tb1.setText(s1);
//Fetch media from media2

InputStream ins;
ins = media2.getStreamData();
PdfReaderUtility pru2 = new PdfReaderUtility();
pru2.readPdfFile(ins);
String s2 = pru.readPdfFile(ins);
tb2.setText(s2);
```

ERROR ::

```
12:31:18,763 SEVERE [org.zkoss] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-5) >>org.zkoss.zk.ui.UiException: com.lowagie.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found.
>>com.lowagie.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: PDF header signature not found.
>>  at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PRTokeniser.checkPdfHeader(PRTokeniser.java:204)
>>  at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:492)
>>  at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:233)
>>  at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:243)
>>  at com.abc.utility.PdfReaderUtility.readPdfFile(PdfReaderUtility.java:15)
>>  at com.abc.controller.ComparisonFormController.onClick$submitButton(ComparisonFormController.java:99)
>>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>>  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>>  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>>  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.GenericEventListener.onEvent(GenericEventListener.java:82)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:2742)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2713)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2654)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:136)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.process0(EventProcessingThreadImpl.java:534)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.sendEvent(EventProcessingThreadImpl.java:126)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.sendEvent(Events.java:338)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.sendEvent(Events.java:348)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent$ForwardListener.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:3180)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:2742)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2713)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:2654)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:136)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.process0(EventProcessingThreadImpl.java:534)
>>  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessingThreadImpl.run(EventProcessingThreadImpl.java:461)
```

Any tip would be nice.

This is my PdfReaderUtility

```
public String readPdfFile(InputStream is) throws IOException {

        // loads the pdf file.
        PdfReader pr = new PdfReader(is);

        // Used for the reading purpose
        PdfTextExtractor pte = new PdfTextExtractor(pr);

        int noOfPages = pr.getNumberOfPages();
        String wholeText="";
        String page="";
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= noOfPages;i++) {
            page = pte.getTextFromPage(i);
            wholeText+=page;
        }

        wholeText.trim();

        return wholeText;
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second file you use the input stream twice, and in the second use it must fail:

```
ins = media2.getStreamData();
PdfReaderUtility pru2 = new PdfReaderUtility();
pru2.readPdfFile(ins);
String s2 = pru.readPdfFile(ins);
```

Look at the last two lines.

I guess that is a copy&paste mistake anyway, those two lines should have been one:

```
ins = media2.getStreamData();
PdfReaderUtility pru2 = new PdfReaderUtility();
String s2 = pru2.readPdfFile(ins);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second snippet of code your using `pru` instead of `pru2`.

```
String s2 = pru.readPdfFile(ins);
```

should be:

```
String s2 = pru2.readPdfFile(ins);
```

**Full Source**

```
//Fetch media from media1
InputStream is;
is = media1.getStreamData();
PdfReaderUtility pru = new PdfReaderUtility();
String s1 = pru.readPdfFile(is);
tb1.setText(s1);
//Fetch media from media2

InputStream ins;
ins = media2.getStreamData();
PdfReaderUtility pru2 = new PdfReaderUtility();
pru2.readPdfFile(ins);
String s2 = pru2.readPdfFile(ins); //replaced pru with pru2
tb2.setText(s2);
```

Comment: @Aayush Kevin's remark covers only part of the problem. The real issue is the line above the one in which he replaced `pru` with `pru2`...

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox and mkl thanks I was so tired I compared the code many times but I missed what you have suggested...